# How to get a specific elemend from combined array?

Tags: php

I have two arrays, then i combines them with array_combine() method and now i want to get a secend elemont of new array in thic case: Ben = 37

```
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");
$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
$a = $c[1];
?>
```

but it outputs erros `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`
Have i made a mistake? Yep but where?

Comment: The keys of your *combined* array would be `Peter`,`Ben` and `Joe`, not `0`, `1`, etc. Do `var_dump($c);` to see the array structure.

Comment: [Did you try to print out the contents of `$c`? If you did you'd know that there's no `1` key](https://eval.in/663927).

Comment: Why did you use `array_combine()` in the first place, if you want to access elements by number? Do you understand what it does?

Comment: Thanks and when i want to acces and get kay and alos value? – Giorgi Khachidze 18 secs ago
     
For example how can i get: Ben = 37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `combine` you got an associative array, where the second element is not "1" but "Ben" :

```
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");
$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
//$a = $c[1];
$a = $c["Ben"];  // KEY="Ben", VALUE="37".
echo $a;
?>
```

Edit #1 : get key "Ben" and its value :

```
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");
$c=array_combine($fname,$age);

$keys = array_keys( $c );
echo $keys[ 1 ] .    // "Ben"
     "=" .
     $c[ $keys[1] ]; // "37".
?>
```

Comment: Thans and when i want to acces and get kay and alos value?

Comment: For example how can i gate: Ben = 37

Comment: @GiorgiKhachidze, you can use `array_keys` to get all the keys in the array. Once you got the keys, you can use them to get the values.

Comment: Can i show me please example based on my code?

Comment: @GiorgiKhachidze, just edited my answer. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`array_combine` uses the first parameter as keys and the second as values. so it goes to the result:

```
Array ( 
    [Peter] => 35 
    [Ben] => 37 
    [Joe] => 43 
)
```

So you can access the age with the name as key.

```
$a = $c['Peter']; // 35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
   $age=array("35","37","43");
   $c=array_combine($fname,$age);
   $a = $c['Ben'];

?>
```